# Can't get onItemSelectedListener to fire with a Spinner?

Tags: android

I've got an adapter that extends from BaseAdapter. I'm using it with a Spinner. I can't get an onItemSelectedListener to fire when an item is selected from it:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
  ..
}

public void foo() {
    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(...);
    adapter.setStuff(new String[] { "foo0", "foo1", "fooN" });

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.foo);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.e("####", "hello?...");
        } 

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
            Log.e("####", "hello?...");
        }
    });
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

The spinner operates fine otherwise, I just don't receive any callbacks when I select an item. Does the callback only work with an ArrayAdapter-derived adapter?

Thanks

Comment: Try calling `setOnItemSelectedListener()` before `setAdapter()`.

Comment: Hi, ok tried that but still nothing. Argh.

Comment: `setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {`  perhaps you have a different `import` instead of `AdapterView`

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your implementation of the adapter, I can only guess that you made a mistake somewhere in the implementation of your adapter. I don't see your implementation of any of the methods. Presumably you *implemented* them, otherwise your code wouldn't compile, but if you didn't provide enough structure, then you'll miss something you need.

I'm curious why you're not just using an ArrayAdapter to back the spinner.